# defmethod specializer on string match

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clos

For numbers, I can specialise on an exact value within a `defmethod` this works:

```lisp
(defgeneric person (attribute)
  (:documentation "attributes of a person"))

(defmethod person ((a number))
  (let ((sum (+ a 10)))
    (format t "The sum of 10 and ~a is ~a" a sum)))

(defmethod person ((a (eql 10)))
    (format t "TENNNNNN!!!"))

> (person 11) ;; The sum of 10 and 11 is 21
> (person 10) ;; TENNNNN!!
```

How can I accomplish the same thing for a string match?

I tried `eq`, `equal` and `string=` but I get an error that says `not a valid parameter specializer name`?

Comment: parameter specializer list only uses `eql`. also look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2541137/4437190

Comment: Generally you can't, as the other comment says.  One fairly mad approach would be to use a readtable which interns strings, and then just define `eql` methods.  I don't want to think about the implications of that for file compilation.

Comment: Build a hash table that maps strings to lambdas, and look up the appropriate function to call via it?